# I need help figuring out how to change values in a pandas dataframe only where identifier keys match

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine i have two tables.

1st

```
customer_id first_name  gender
3343        Cristabel   female
2469        Kermie      male
996         Aura        female
1628        Hermione    female
2696        Isabelle    female
```

2nd

```
customer_id first_name  gender
3343        Cristabel   u
2469        Kermie      u
996         Aura        u
1628        Hermione    u
2696        Isabelle    u
1689        Jhon        male
5698        Albert      male
```

I want to change the gender attribute only for the rows with 'u' in table 2 with the corresponding gender from table 1.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and then replace `u` values by another column with `_`:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on=['customer_id','first_name'], how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
df2['gender'] = df2['gender'].mask(df2['gender'] == 'u', df2.pop('gender_'))
print (df2)
  customer_id first_name  gender
0         3343  Cristabel  female
1         2469     Kermie    male
2          996       Aura  female
3         1628   Hermione  female
4         2696   Isabelle  female
5         1689       Jhon    male
6         5698     Albert    male
```

If want match only by `customer_id` not by both columns here is alternative:

```
mask = df2['gender'] == 'u'
s = df1.set_index('customer_id')['gender']
df2.loc[mask, 'gender'] = df2.loc[mask, 'customer_id'].map(s).fillna(df2['gender'])
print (df2)
   customer_id first_name  gender
0         3343  Cristabel  female
1         2469     Kermie    male
2          996       Aura  female
3         1628   Hermione  female
4         2696   Isabelle  female
5         1689       Jhon    male
6         5698     Albert    male
```

Comment: Why make it so complex? a simple replace() will do

Comment: @Capie - Because your solution not match by `customer_id, first_name`, so is wrong

Comment: @jezrael Feel free to try it yourself, works fine....

Comment: @Capie check `Kermie` row, it has to be `male`

Comment: @jezrael oh, I thought table1  was the expected result and table 2 the input....my bad...